# How to start Activity from another project

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, windows-phone

I`m working at weather application for android and windows-phone. So I write common code in another project in "Weather.Api(Portable)" in "Parsing Class". "Weather.Droid" is used for Android.[image]

The code of ParsingClass is following:

```
    public static string tempGlobal;
    public static string cityTextGlobal;
    private static string GovnoTemperature;

    public async  Task<string> dataByCity(string city)
    {
        var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&APPID="+AppID;

        //ТОРМОЗИТ ЗДЕСЬ / BRAKES HERE
        await FetchAsync(url);
        return city;
    }

    public async Task<double> Data_down(double lat, double lon)
    {

        var url = String.Format(
          "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&units=metric&APPID=" + AppID);

        //ТОРМОЗИТ ЗДЕСЬ / BRAKES HERE
        await FetchAsync(url);

        return lat;
    }

    public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;

        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var json = jsonString;

        JsonValue firstitem = json;
        var mydata = JObject.Parse(json);

        cityTextGlobal = (mydata["name"]).ToString();

        string GovnoData = (mydata["main"]).ToString();

        //spliting string
        string[] values = GovnoData.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = values[i].Trim();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //tempGlobal = values[i];
                GovnoTemperature = values[i];
            }
        }
        tempGlobal = null;
        foreach (char c in GovnoTemperature)
        {
            if (c == '.')
            {
                break;
            }
            if (c == '-' || char.IsDigit(c) == true || c == '.')
            {
                tempGlobal += c.ToString();
            }
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
}

public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public int temp_min { get; set; }
    public int temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

}

I need to start MainActivity of "Weather.Droid" from method:

> public async Task FetchAsync(string url)

before it returns:

> jsonString

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to start MainActivity of "Weather.Droid" from method:
>
> public async Task FetchAsync(string url)

You can't start the MainActivity from Droid project directly. But as @SKall said, you can use `Action<Intent>` in your `FetchAsync` Method:

```
//add Action<Intent> as and Intent as parameters
public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url,Action<Intent> navigationFunc,Intent intent)
{
    string jsonString;
    ...
    navigationFunc(intent);//Invoke the action
    return jsonString;
}
```

Then use it in your Droid Project:

```
ParsingClass parsing = new ParsingClass();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
await parsing.FetchAsync("url", StartActivity, intent);
```

Comment: Intent is in the Android namespace so you cannot use it. Just create a plain Action instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are after is dependency injection. Declare an interface in the portable project and then implement it in the Droid/iOS/??? projects that you support.

I have created an abstraction of IOC in XLabs community project. Matt Whetton has written some pretty good instructions on how to use it: http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-xamarin-forms-labs-xaml-mvvm-ioc/

The following method isn't ideal but it is a bit unclear why you would need to call the activity start at least this would give you some idea.

On the portable side:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static async Task<string> Fetch(string url, Action onComplete = null)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);


        onComplete?.Invoke();
        return url;
    }
}
```

On Android side (this would be your splash screen or application if your intent is to do this fetch before the main screen comes up):

```
[Activity(Label = "App5", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Class1.Fetch("test", () =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(OtherActivity));
            this.RunOnUiThread(() => StartActivity(intent));
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsCompleted) Log.Debug("Fetch", t.Result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to call from ParsingClass any method that is placed in Weater.Droid project. This is my problem.

Comment: Are you calling this method from the Android project? If so you can add an Action to the method parameters and invoke it before the method returns. If not then IOC is your best option.

Comment: I wrote public method, that starts the needed activity in android project. But the problem was to call this method from Weather.Api project. I tried to make a reference. But it was impossible to do that. The text of this error is: A reference Weather.Droid could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency